# Chrome devtools: Drop into debugger without switching to Sources tab

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector, javascript-debugger

If I put the [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement in my JavaScript source with the Chrome devtools open, it'll stop execution so I can interactively explore the current context from the console. It's really awesome.

But unfortunately it will also switch to the Sources tab and display the line where the `debugger` statement happened. Most of the time, I want to type JavaScript commands, so I have to manually switch back to the Console tab.

Can I avoid the tab-switching and stay in the Console tab?

Or am I using it wrong?

Comment: I think debugger performs the same action every time. But pressing "ESC" shows the console when in Sources. I never find myself using the Console tab, because debugging involves 'stepping' 90% the time anyway.

Comment: I gave you my answer, but may I ask you why you use `debugger` instead of a more flexible breakpoint?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and @joecritch too! I use `debugger` instead of breakpoints because I usually have my source open in my editor (in CoffeeScript actually), so it's easy to add a `debugger` line. I'd have to navigate through the Sources tab to locate the point I'm interested in in order to set a breakpoint, so that takes much longer.

Comment: I noticed the same problem and reported it as a "bug" https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=609248

Comment: This is one of the worst design decisions by Google.  I'm finding myself constantly switching back and forth between tabs. Like the OP, I just want the tab to stay on 'console'.  Please give us the option so we can decide if we want the default behavior or not.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like Chrome added a preference for this in the intervening 9 years: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69216922/66673

Quoting that answer:

> I had the same issue and it was driving me nuts! The way I managed it to stop switching was to go to into the DevTools settings -> Preferences.
>
> Under Sources options, uncheck Focus Sources panel when triggering a breakpoint.

Comment: Stupid, annoying default behavior by Chrome--I had no breakpoint, yet it does the dev-tools-tab-focus-to-Sources with every interaction of my UI.  Maddening

Answer (score 32):

Right-click on the source-tab and select 'move to bottom'.
[image]

Comment: Best option at the moment.

Comment: I love you, dude... You saved me a lot of frustration.

Comment: Nice! Side tip: Press 'esc' to toggle the bottom panel on/off.

Answer (score -2):

There's a reason for that - and is that whenever the code has stopped, because of a breakpoint or a `debugger` statement, you'd usually want to actually see *where* the execution has stopped. So, the developer tools switches to the Scripts/Sources tab, and this is a common behaviour among the major browsers, that may also show the local variables, the call stack and so on.

The best thing you can do is to keep the console frame always open, so you're ready to work. Just press Esc or click on the second icon on the lower left corner. That's what I usually do.

Switch to the Console tab when you expect to get a large response from the command you type.

Comment: You've explained why `debugger` behaves the way it does, but you didn't answer the question, which was "Can I avoid the tab-switching and stay in the Console tab?" Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I've suggested what's the best you can do. I think it answers the question pretty clearly.

Comment: Not an answer to the question