# How to make Google Chrome Dev Tool Stay on Console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Every time I refresh the page Google Chrome Dev Tools switches to Sources tab which is getting very annoying. There is no breakpoint and there is no error so showing me random source files is pretty useless and damn irritating. It does not always do this for all web sites. If I have Console tab selected, how can I force it to stay on Console when refreshing? (67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: This worked for me, similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65993008/3163087